# My tabs don't change in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a page with several tabs. Each tab has different content. I am using bootstrap and angular and I want to be able to switch between different tabs and mark the active tab.

HTML

```
<div class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top'>
    <div class='container'>
        <a href='index.html' class='navbar-brand'><img src="Pictures/logo.png"></a>
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
            <li><a href='tickets.html'>Products</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aboutModal">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" ng-controller="TabController as tab">
    <h3>Vertical Pills</h3>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="productTabs" ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(1)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Towels</a></li>
            <li class="productTabs" ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(2)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Sheets</a></li>
            <li class="productTabs" ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(3)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Clothes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" ng-show="tab.isSet(1)">
            <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="sheets" ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
            <h4>
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="clothes" ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
            <h4>
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('products', []);



app.controller("TabController", function() {
    this.tab = 1;
    this.setTab = function(selectedTab) {
        this.tab = selectedTab;
    };
    this.isSet = function(givenTab) {
        return this.tab === givenTab;
    };
});

})
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing or if I'm simply just placed something wrongly?

I'm quite new to angular so there might be a lot wrong with this code but some help on the way would be appreciated :)

Comment: what's your goal?

Comment: to switch between the tabs.

Comment: You forgot to self invoke the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script and html like below,

1) Register your parent block with the angular ***ng-app*** directive

```
<div ng-app="products">
```

2) Registering the controller should be like ***ng-controller="TabController"*** not *ng-controller="TabController as tab"*

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="TabController">
```

3) Remove the ***parent function*** from script

4) In angularjs ***use the $scope*** to register your properties. Using $scope will be like this,

```
app.controller("TabController", function($scope) {
          $scope.selectedTab = 1;
          $scope.setTab = function(tabIndex) {
             $scope.selectedTab = tabIndex;
          };
});
```

5) Use the ***$scope.selectedTab in html*** to change the tab index and ***show/hide the description***,

```
<li class="productTabs" ng-class="{active:selectedTab == 1}">


<div class="col-md-3" ng-show="selectedTab == 1">
```

Run the below snippet for output.

```js
var app = angular.module('products', []);
app.controller("TabController", function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedTab = 1;
  $scope.setTab = function(tabIndex) {
    $scope.selectedTab = tabIndex;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="products">
  <div class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top'>
    <div class='container'>
      <a href='index.html' class='navbar-brand'>
        <img src="Pictures/logo.png">
      </a>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href='tickets.html'>Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aboutModal">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="TabController">
    <h3>Vertical Pills</h3>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="productTabs" ng-class="{active:selectedTab == 1}"><a ng-click="setTab(1)">Towels</a>
        </li>
        <li class="productTabs" ng-class="{active:selectedTab == 2}"><a ng-click="setTab(2)">Sheets</a>
        </li>
        <li class="productTabs" ng-class="{active:selectedTab == 3}"><a ng-click="setTab(3)">Clothes</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3" ng-show="selectedTab == 1">
        <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="sheets" ng-show="selectedTab == 2">
        <h4>
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="clothes" ng-show="selectedTab == 3">
        <h4>
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.
            </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```